# Captura de informações com "trava" em python

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, algoritmo, while

`Olá, estou criando um algoritmo e eu preciso que ele capture varias informações de usuários diferentes em laço, porem quero por uma trava onde na parte de nome só aceite alpha, e na parte do tempo só aceite números inteiros, dessa forma se a pessoa coloca outra coisa que não corresponde, ele peça novamente os dados e fique nesse loop ate que os dados sejam inseridos corretamente.

[image: codigo]

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro trabalhar com expressão regular, utilizando a biblioteca `re` do Python.
Assim você consegue validar a entrada do usuário usando o método `math`, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
import re

loop = True
while loop:
    user = input('Digite nome do usuario: ')
    math = re.match('[A-Za-z]*$',user)
    if math == None:
        print('Digite apenas valores alfabeticos.')
    else:
        loop = False
        while True:
            tempo = input('Digite de espera no app em segundos: ')
            math = re.match('^[0-9]*$',tempo)
            if math == None:
                print('Digite apenas valores numericos')
            else:
                break
```